# {"title":"Unsupported Media Type",Error for no matter what i try :I(

Tags: python, python-requests

Below is my code, and no matter what I try I always get 415. Can someone please look and let me know what am I missing.

Returned response:

```
{"title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"detail":"This resource supports only application/json,application/octet-stream,application/xml,application/*+json,text/plain,text/xml,application/x-www-form-urlencoded,application/*+xml,multipart/form-data,*/*, but you've sent request with Content-Type application/octet-stream
```

Code:

```
import requests,json

url= "https://x.y.x.z"
headers= {'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': 't0K3N'}
payload= {'isDeleted': 'false',*emphasized text*}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload,ensure_ascii=True),verify= False)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Try `response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)` as shown in the [example in the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: tried that as well.. but no luck

Comment: `sent request with Content-Type -----Code-----`. What is `-----Code-----` supposed to be? What Content-Type does the application think you sent it?

Comment: but you've sent request with Content-Type application/octet-stream

Comment: Are you able to provide us with the actual URL? My instinct says to verify that the server actually supports the types it says it supports.

Answer (score 0):

The error reads

> This resource supports only application/json [... and a bunch of other types]

The way to announce a media type to the receiving server is by setting a `Content-Type` header.

```
headers= {
    'Accept': 'application/json',                         # this is the data type you expect for a response
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': 't0K3N',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',    # this is the data type you send
}

payload = {'isDeleted': 'false', 'and': 'some more data'}
data = json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=True)

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=data,verify= False)

# response will be JSON-encoded if the server is well-behaved
```

Comment: i tried that too but i get the same error

Comment: That's not possible. :) The server would only complain if you don't declare a content type, or declare an unacceptable one (such as `text/html`). Are you sure there are no typos anywhere? Update your question with the code you're actually using.